Query to extract addresses in several parts of Germany is not working via QuickOSM
I a trying to extract addresses from the OpenStreetMap as polygons via QuickOSM using the keys: addr:street, addr:housenumber and addr:city.
That works quite well, but not in every part of Germany. For example in Bavaria. None of my Querys which included Bavarian addresses worked.
Does anybody know a Solution to this Problem?

Welcome to the GIS SE community :) Can you please show us these queries? Also, are you interested in addresses as points or as buildings (polygons)?

Did you check how the addresses that you are looking for are spelled ? Like double checking on the OSM site how the address in your region of interest is saved in OSM.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

At least here the addresses are put on nodes https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/8657138208. But the tagging of addresses in OSM is a mess. Perhaps you should consider using software or services which normalize the addresses, for example https://nominatim.org/release-docs/3.4/.

@user30184 OK, that's indeed true. But looking e.g. for addr:street=Clara-Schumann-Straße with QuickOSM should still find both nodes and polygons, right? So the problem must be something else?

Thanks Guys for your qick answers, and sry for my late responding to it!
A random address i've tested was this one:
[out:xml] [timeout:25];
(
node["addr:street"="Kopfsberg"]["addr:housenumber"="1"]"addr:city"="Iggensbach";
way["addr:street"="Kopfsberg"]["addr:housenumber"="1"]"addr:city"="Iggensbach";
relation["addr:street"="Kopfsberg"]["addr:housenumber"="1"]"addr:city"="Iggensbach";
);
(._;>;);
out body;
I really dont get it, sometimes there is a result but most of the time it cant find anything...
